# Git - How to move subpath to new branch and push it when server doesn't allow commit with difference id?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, commit

I have a repository with structure like this:

```
/MyProject
   /Module1
   /Module2
   /Experimental
      /Module1
      /Module2
```

In which, Experimental is contain the experimental code; I know this is not the best practice for Git, but people did it in the past. Now, we need to make Experimental become a branch for MyProject. 
I used

```
git subtree split -P Experimental -b Experimental_Branch
```

And successfully create a new branch on my local with all preserved history commits. But when I push it to the origin, I got a lot of messages:

```
 ! [remote rejected] Experimental_Branch -> Experimental_Branch (aae0fd6b9bf47b723cd96c95653faa3c1b7599e8 by someone <someone@email.com> was not committed by me <me@email.com>)
```

I know this because Git server is configured to prevent an user to push other's commit. But then we have so many people commit to this already, so no one is able to push this to server. 
We don't care about who did commit which revision, but only the change and commit logs - How can I push this? Could I reset all commits to mine id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We don't care about who did commit which revision, but only the change and commit logs

Then you could:

- change the past commits to reset them to  `me <me@email.com>` (with [git filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), as in [this GitHub script](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info)).
- Then `git push` that branch.